# Wrong referencing of js files in Vue 3 with an extra .map added

Tags: vue.js

On my local machines the files are being referenced well.

```
<script src="assets/vendors/popper.js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/jquery-scrollLock/jquery-scrollLock.min.js"></script>
```

But I when deploy on the server, the files references changes and an extra .map is added leading to 404

for example

```
assets/vendors/popper.js/popper.min.js.map
```

So the full path url becomes

https://dashboard.craftcollect.africa/parking/assets/vendors/popper.js/popper.min.js.map

instead of

https://dashboard.craftcollect.africa/parking/assets/vendors/popper.js/popper.min.js

Comment: You most likely misidentified the problem. You didn't explain it in details and it needs to be confirmed that this affects something besides source maps. Currently it looks like .map  files just are unavailable in production, for one reason or another. They are loaded in addition to .js files, not in place of them